# How to use a second nameserver if the first can't resolve a domain?

Tags: dns, resolv.conf

How can I configure a linux computer to use a second DNS server if the default server fails to find the IP for a domain?

I tried adding both to `/etc/resolv.conf` but then it will only try the second `nameserver` if the first name server is not available.  I want to try the second name server if the first is available but unable to resolve the domain.

I don't have control over either name server so I can't configure one to recurse to the other.  Would running my own DNS server that recurses to both be a solution?

Comment: Try adding `options rotate`, alternatively use dnsmasq

Comment: As Pat said in an answer, it can't really be done, there are only workarounds. My workaround is to use network namespaces (`ip netns`), which allows me to prioritise different resolvers depending on what I'm working on.

Comment: *rotate Sets RES_ROTATE in _res.options, which causes round-robin selection of name servers from among those listed.  This has the effect  of
                     spreading the query load among all listed servers, rather than having all clients try the first listed server first every time.* - I don't know but this option could very well help.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov yeah, that's one of the more common workarounds mentioned when you try looking up how to fix this. As you say, it probably helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Linux DNS resolver isn't good at handling the concept of multiple separate DNS namespaces.  If you send a query to a particular DNS server, and it returns an authoritative `NXDOMAIN`, it's basically saying "I am telling you for an absolute fact that this name does not exist", and the resolver "knows" that it doesn't need to search any further.  I am not aware of any option you can set in `resolv.conf` or anywhere else that would change this behavior.

Whenever I've had to do anything like this, the only option I've found was to run my own DNS server to provide a "split DNS" setup, and configure it so certain names are resolved by querying one set of DNS servers, and other names are resolved by querying a different set.  The alternate solution suggested in a comment of using `dnsmasq` is also viable.

Comment: This is the best explanation I've seen so far about why fallback DNS in resolv.conf doesn't really work as expected.

Comment: How would dnsmasq solve this?  As I understand that just caches dns requests. Wouldn't it cache `NXDOMAIN` responses from the default name server?

Comment: You could potentially use `dnsmasq` to redirect queries to alternate servers, though this does require that you know in advance which names would have to go to the alternate servers.  It admittedly doesn't address the general problem you've posed.

Comment: I run my own recursive (and validating) nameserver. IMHO this is a good option with great possibilities to customize it for your particular setup. But there are some (misconfigured or corporate - misconfigured by design) networks, where this setup is not possible (due to restrictions to DNS packets).

Answer (score 0):

For a use case involving a local DNS server that isn't available at all times (as in spawned by `libvirtd`), it's possible to define it in `netconfig` under `NETCONFIG_DNS_STATIC_SERVERS`.

The DNS merge order is defined under `NETCONFIG_DNS_POLICY`. `STATIC` being the first entry, it will be merged ahead of all the other entries (* - stands for all interfaces defined in `ifcfg-*ifname*` files) or `NetworkManager`.

To ensure the DNS does not become stuck querying a potentially non-responsive server, set a minimal timeout value and querying in rotation: `rotate timeout:1`

TL;DR
Here's the final `/etc/sysconfig/network/config`:

```
NETCONFIG_DNS_POLICY="STATIC * NetworkManager"
NETCONFIG_DNS_STATIC_SERVERS="192.168.100.1"
NETCONFIG_DNS_RESOLVER_OPTIONS="rotate timeout:1"
```

and the resulting entries in /etc/resolv.conf:

```
options options rotate timeout:1
search lan
nameserver 192.168.100.1
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

192.168.1.1 is provided via DHCP to NetworkManager and 192.168.100.1 is the statically defined server that may not be available at all times (e.g. when libvirtd is down).

If it's the NetworkManager that provides all the DNS records, it's also possible to set `dns-priority` per each profile for statically defined DNS entries. It's not possible to set a statically defined DNS server ahead of the primary DNS server from DHCP. All additional DNS servers in any profiles involving DHCP are secondary.

Comment: I believe you have misunderstood the question.

Comment: I didn't, just provided a use case where the inability to ignore an NXDOMAIN can be work around somehow. If one of the DNS servers   (192.168.100.1) can be made to forward requests to the other as in my case, then that might work. 'options rotate' alone isn't enough, as it will result in failures.